# What is the meaning of 'dismiss'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot understand the meaning of 'dismiss' in this sentence. 'Dismiss' doesn't mean 'ignore' or 'fire'? In this context, I guess 'dismiss' would have the positive meaning, but the meaning in dictionary doesn't match with that.

"Some [school] districts have found ways to identify, improve, and as necessary,
**dismiss** teachers using strategies like peer assistance and evaluation that offer intensive mentoring and review panels.
These and other approaches should be the focus of experimentation by states and districts."

Comment: Dismiss means fire (terminate) from their jobs.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the sentence closely a few times, you will understand that 'peer assistance and evaluation' are strategies that are used to 'identify, improve and as necessary, dismiss teachers'.

It looks to me that the strategies listed above are used to evaluate teachers and if needed 'dismiss' them if these strategies are not followed. So the word 'dismiss' has been used in the right meaning.

Not really happy with the way the sentence has been formed, but it sure could've been made simpler.